# Creating a models.UniqueConstraint in abstract model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am creating an abstract model for my django app, `SrdObject`. One of the characteristics of my model is that it has a pair of fields that, taken together, must be unique: 'name' and the foreign key 'module'.

Here is an example of what I had

```
class SrdObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s', blank=False, null=False, default='default')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name', 'module']
        ordering = ['name']
        abstract = True
```

This seemed to be working ok, but the `unique_together` attribute has been marked as deprecated by django (See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)), so I changed it to this

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'module'], name='unique-in-module')
    ]
    ordering = ['name']
    abstract = True
```

This doesn't work because the name field must be unique, and since this is an abstract class, the constraint is repeated over several models.

I also tried

```
models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'module'], name='{}-unique-in-module'.format(model_name))
```

But obviously this falls into scoping problems, so I tried a decorator method

```
def add_unique_in_module_constraint(cls):
    cls._meta.constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'module'], name='unique-in-module')
    ]
    return cls

@add_unique_in_module_constraint
class SrdObject(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        abstract = True
```

But this didn't seem to do anything.

So how do I create a models.UniqueConstraint in abstract model if every constraint needs a unique name attribute?

Comment: Just to clarify - the name/module uniqueness is across all models that inherit from SrdObject? 

ie. assuming we have two models - SrdObjectA and SrdObjectB - that inherit from SrdObject, if I have a SrdObjectA with name of 'test' and module id of 1, then I cannot also have a SrdObject with a name of 'test' and a module id of 1?

Comment: That is not a requirement. Every SrdObject model has its own namespace

Answer (score 9):

***LATEST UPDATE***

Since 3rd version you finally can do that by [specifying interpolation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.name):

```
Changed in Django 3.0:
Interpolation of '%(app_label)s' and '%(class)s' was added.
```

Example:

```py
UniqueConstraint(fields=['room', 'date'], name='%(app_label)s_unique_booking')
```

***OLD (Django < 3.0)***

You can't do that, same problem for me, so sad...

Source: [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#module-django.db.models.constraints)

> Constraints in abstract base classes
>
> > You must always specify a unique name for the constraint. As such, you cannot normally specify a constraint on an abstract base class, since the Meta.constraints option is inherited by subclasses, with exactly the same values for the attributes (including name) each time. Instead, specify the constraints option on subclasses directly, providing a unique name for each constraint.

Comment: What the hell does that mean?  Interpolation?

Comment: @NoName, you can name it as you like, i just copied that from the official docs

Comment: @NoName added example

Answer (score 0):

I took this model setup:

```
class Module(models.Model):
    pass


class SrdObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s', blank=False, null=False, default='default')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'module'], name='unique-in-module')
        ]
        ordering = ['name']
        abstract = True


class SrdObjectA(SrdObject):
    pass


class SrdObjectB(SrdObject):
    pass
```

And then ran these tests:

```
class TestSrdObject(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.module = Module.objects.create()
        SrdObjectA.objects.create(name='A', module=cls.module)

    def test_unique_applies_to_same_model(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            SrdObjectA.objects.create(name='A', module=self.module)

    def test_unique_does_not_apply_to_different_model(self):
        self.assertTrue(SrdObjectB.objects.create(name='A', module=self.module))
```

And they pass. Perhaps I'm still missing the problem you're running into?

Comment: When I attempt to migrate the db I get `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "unique-in-module" already exists`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What database do you use? And could you possibly share what your migration file looks like?